# Trouble exposing port on Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, docker

I want to deploy a .Net Framework application to ACI that has a web frontend. The programm is set to start the web service on port 8090, so I entered that in the "ports" section of the ACI setup and set a DNS name label. As far as I understood it, this should be enough to make the website publicly available, but I get the "Website not available" error message.

I ran the container locally and it works just fine. I also added the EXPOSE command to the Dockerfile, but that didn't help either. The image is based on a .Net Framework Windows Server Core 2016 image, which should work with Azure.

Comment: how do you deploy container to aci? just following this tutorial should work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-deploy-app

Comment: Do you check if the container instance is in the running state?

Comment: I followed the turorial and yes it is running. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Which image do you use? The ACI just supports some windows images.

Comment: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2016 and mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2016

Comment: Take a look at the [supported windows images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-faq#what-windows-base-os-images-are-supported).

Comment: It says right there that my image is supported...

Comment: How do you run the image locally? and how do you run the image in the ACI?

Comment: Well, locally I run it with the docker run commad mapping port 8090 of the container to my own 8090 an in Azure I use the web interface, opening port 8090 in the network tab and providing a DNS name so I get a FQDN. My understanding was that this FQDN would map to the opened port.

Comment: Yes, the steps are right. How do you access the ACI through the browser? Do you use the FQDN with the port?

Comment: Until just now I only used the FQDN, which gave me the error message from my question. Now I tried it in combination with the port and it didn't even manage to connect to anything, I'm just getting an error from my browser that the connection was reset while the site was loading.

Comment: Do you try just use the public IP with the port?

Comment: Same result as before

Comment: Any more details in the logs of the ACI?

Comment: No, just that the webserver has started successfully.

Comment: It's using the syntax `http://+:8090`, could that be an issue?

Comment: Generally, if you can run the image locally successfully and the base image is supported in ACI, then the image can run successfully in ACI as it does locally. By the way, you can @me if you send the message to me.

Comment: Nvm I changed everything to port 80 and it worked, I'm about to puke. But thanks for all the help, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone seeing this in the future: It seems you can only expose web interfaces on port 80.